# 1994 toyota 4runner manual broken transfer case

Tags: toyota, transfer-case, 4runner

My 1994 4runner (manual) starts and goes into gear, but will not move. If the transfer case is broken, can I take out drive 4 wheel drive and drive it in 2 wheel drive?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

tl dr: No

The transfer case sits at the back of the transmission. It has two drive shafts which come off of it, one to the front and one to the back. You'd have to install a different transmission and driveline to the rear in order to do what you are talking about. It would be far cheaper (and easier) to get a transfer case fixed or replaced than to go about what you are suggesting.

With that said, what makes you think it would be the transfer case? Seeing as how this is a manual transmission, I'd suspect the clutch had gone out before I'd suspect the transfer case, unless there was something specific which happened to make you believe it's the t-case.

Comment: Thank you.
I didn't have a reason why i thought it was the t.c.
The clutch was a thought also. I do not know a lot about these type of things, that is why i came here for answers. The Q. about the 4 wheel to 2 wheel was because i actually bought a auto. 4 wheel d. Dodge Duran-go and the 4 wheel drive was taken out.... when i bought it. and i drove it 2 wheel until i received the part to make it 4 wheel drive again. Thought maybe i could do the same with my runner.

Comment: @user35894 - What they did was remove the front drive shaft. That makes it a 2wd, but the transfer case is still in place and would not work for what you are suggesting for the 4Runner if the transfer case is bad.

Comment: The answer here tells you why you can't do what you want and points you in a possible direction for the real problem.